# String Literal Too Long for Oracle SQL Macro

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to create an Oracle SQL Macro for a very long SQL statement. Because of the length of the SQL statement however, I'm getting the 'string literal too long' error. **Has anyone found a way to get around this error?**

Example when creating macro:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MACRO_FUNC(arg1 VARCHAR2)
RETURN CLOB SQL_MACRO IS
BEGIN

RETURN TO_CLOB('

*Very long SELECT statement here*

');

END;
```

At first I had the SELECT statement as a string literal (ex. q'*SELECT statement*') but because I was getting the 'string literal too long' error, I threw the SELECT statement into a TO_CLOB() function but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that a string literal `'...'` is limited to 4000 bytes in each literal. What you need to do is either: split the literal up into smaller literals; or read the literal from a file.

In your case:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MACRO_FUNC(arg1 VARCHAR2)
RETURN CLOB SQL_MACRO IS
BEGIN

RETURN EMPTY_CLOB()
       || 'First 4000 bytes of the statement'
       || 'Second 4000 bytes of the statement'
       -- ...
       || 'Nth 4000 bytes of the statement';

END;
```

or:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION MACRO_FUNC(arg1 VARCHAR2)
RETURN CLOB SQL_MACRO IS
BEGIN

RETURN TO_CLOB('First 4000 bytes of the statement')
       || 'Second 4000 bytes of the statement'
       -- ...
       || 'Nth 4000 bytes of the statement';

END;
```